# Can ‘calorific value’ be used without an article?

Tags: articles

While reading the following sentence, I was wondering why the term *calorific value* doesn't take an article. I have been taught that a singular noun always takes an article unless it is part of an idiomatic construction. Is there any other rule that I am missing?

> A good fuel should possess *high calorific value* because *calorific value*
>   determines the efficiency of the fuel.

Comment: Mass/non-count nouns do not require determiners, but I wouldn’t call _calorific value_ a non-count noun as such. Was this written by a native speaker? It strikes me as being slightly unidiomatic, partly because of the missing determiners (though I’ll admit I can’t quite figure out why I only find it slightly inelegant here and not ungrammatical), but also because _possess_ seems an oddly anthropomorphic verb to use for this. It would be much more natural to me to just say, “A good fuel should have a high calorific value”.

Comment: Does *length* take an article?

Comment: It was indeed written by a non-native speaker. The "value" in the example sentence is very much a count noun. Also, My question related to (non)use of an article before such nouns in general. Consider also the following sentence: "Heat value or calorific value determines the energy content of a fuel". TIA.

Comment: Is it "calorific value" or caloric value?

Comment: This is fairly common among "The New Englishes". The zero article is used in association with a non-specific instance. If *a good fuel* was replaced by some particular fuel, it would be more likely to get an article. Using a general category (good fuel) makes the property (calorific value) intrinsic to the category. So although it is measurable for a particular fuel, it is not measurable for the category. Hence a more conceptual take on what "high calorific value" means is warranted. [Zero Article](https://www.thoughtco.com/zero-article-grammar-1692619) - see comment in first paragraph.

Comment: For some reason, 'high' seems to me not to need an article. Replace 'high' with 'large' and the article is definitely needed.

Comment: Hi Nigel, the second 'calorific value'?